# sendmail не отправляет почту

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, email, sendmail

Борюсь с этой проблемой уже неделю: sendmail пишет, что все успешно отправлено, однако в ящик сообщение не приходит, вот что в логах:

> Jun 26 19:38:41 server sm-mta[6139]: u5QGcflo006139:
>   from=, size=336, class=0, nrcpts=1,
>   msgid=<201606261638.u5QGceek006138@server.Dlink>, proto=ESMTP,
>   daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
>
> Jun 26 19:38:41 server sendmail[6138]: u5QGceek006138:
>   to=мойемейл@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:01,
>   xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30115, relay=[127.0.0.1]
>   [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u5QGcflo006139 Message accepted for
>   delivery)

Может быть сам gmail не пропускает? Тогда почему?

---

Проблема не решена, но причина ясна. Поставил *postfix*, решил отправить письмо, в логах:

> connection timed out

Немного проверив, я понял причину: провайдер блокирует порт 25 для исходящих соединений, без него никак.

Comment: *relay=[127.0.0.1]* — а какой процесс у вас слушает 25-й порт на этом ip-адресе?

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          29864       5770/sendmail: MTA:

Comment: т.е., вы настроили так, чтобы программа сама себе письма отправляла. вероятно, это не совсем то, что вам требуется. рекомендую воспользоваться каким-нибудь руководством.

Comment: увы, но никакого руководства по этому в гугле не нашел :(

Comment: попробуйте почитать здесь: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/ru/books/handbook/sendmail.html в частности пункт 24.3.4

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как проблема — у провайдера.

Comment: Это не проблема провайдера у меня на локалке в контейнере постфикс отправляет мыло и без порта.

Comment: используйте другой порт: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=ru